# render method url dosen't match original url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say i have a form which is at:

> /categories/new

When form input is invalid I call render. Classic example:

```
  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      flash[:success] = 'Category successfully created.'
      redirect_to @category
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

My question is, why site path after call to render is just:

> /categories

and not:

> /categories/new

As I understand 'new' form should be rendered on the same page and those two paths clearly aren't the same.

As commenters suggested here is additional info:

related routes:

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :topics, name_prefix: 'category_',
                       except: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end
```

category new action:

```
  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end
```

Comment: can you show the related routes?

Comment: Please share the routes as Gaston Suggested. Also please share method new!

Comment: I doubt its related specifically to my app. I checked another one from michael hartl tutorial and it's behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't confuse what the url shows with what is actually rendered.

**Short Answer**

When you initially input your form you are actually doing a `POST` to `/categories`. This of course maps to the `create` action in your controller which when failing validation causes the new form to render - it isn't a redirect so the url won't change - the url remains the same as it did when you entered the action.

**Detailed Explanation**

When you invoke `/categories/new` you are actually being routed to the `new` action on the categories controller.

Your `new` action then sets any instance variables, for example @category, and rails will render the new.html.erb which contains your new category form.

When you submit the form it actually is doing a http `POST` to `/categories`, which routes to the `create` action of your categories controller. That url and http method is a result of what is generated from the form_for helper:

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
```

This is why the url changes from `/categories/new` to `/categories`

Now the `create` action if it fails the validation simply renders the new form - it is not redirecting anywhere - the url remains unchanged from what it was when it entered this action - meaning, it remains as `/categories`.

Don't confuse the change in url with a redirection it's just that the form is posting to a different url than /categories/new, and the change in url is actually just a cosmetic issue.

Now if it is a concern to you, you can change the routing to something like the following:

```
  resources :categories, except: [:create, :new]

  post     'new_category' => 'categories#create'
  get      'new_category' => 'categories#new'
```

This is mapping the POST and GET http methods to /new_category so the url appears the same for the new and create action invocations. Note you do need to change the url in the form_for helper to use this new route:

```
<%= form_for @category, url: 'new_category' do |f| %>
```

Comment: That explains everything. Thanks.

Comment: your welcome ... glad i could help ... on reflection I'm considering moving and editing my fuller explanation from the other question to this one. Your question is more succinct

Comment: That may be a good idea since I searched stackoverflow for an answer before asking and didn't find question You have linked here.